# How to merge multiple json files with maintaining schema?

Tags: python, json

i have multiple json files (Benoni_0-100.json etc) that looks like this:

```
{
   "matches":[
      {
         "platformId":"TR1",
         "gameId":379560441,
         "champion":62,
         "queue":410,
         "season":7,
         "timestamp":1460529442141,
         "role":"NONE",
         "lane":"JUNGLE"
      }
   ],
   "startIndex":4200,
   "endIndex":4201,
   "totalGames":4201
}
```

When i try to merge to two files with the following code, it works.

```
import json

with open("Benoni_0-100.json") as fo:
    data1 = json.load(fo)

with open("Benoni_100-200.json") as fo:
    data2 = json.load(fo)

data1['matches'].extend(data2['matches'])

with open("test.json", "w") as fo:
    json.dump(data1, fo)
```

However i have multiple files and want to batch merge. When i try it with the following code, it fails.

```
data = '{"matches": []}'
folder = glob.glob("*.json")
for filename in folder:
    with open(filename) as file:
        data1 = json.loads(data)
        datanew = json.load(file)
        data1['matches'].extend(datanew['matches'])
with open("test.json", "w") as fo:
    json.dump(data1, fo)
```

The output is:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I've been trying various methods for hours and failed. Can anyone help me?

EDIT: Solved it with the following code.

```
data = '{"matches": []}'
data_1 = json.loads(data)
folder = glob.glob("*.json")

for filename in folder:
    try:
        with open(filename) as fo:
            data_new = json.load(fo)
            data_1['matches'].extend(data_new['matches'])
    except:
        print(filename)

with open("test.json", "w") as fo:
    json.dump(data_1, fo)
```

Comment: Is `data1 = json.loads(data)` supposed to be inside the loop?  Anyway this shouldn't solve your problem. Check the `filename` that causes error

Answer (score 0):

'matches' is a list, might as well concactenate it

```
dict['matches'] += otherdict['matches']
```

in the case you're not extending dicts, but lists
you have a list of dicts

Comment: Thanks, this is actually very useful

Answer (score 0):

Running your batch merge code, I don't get any errors, and the output is stored in `test.json`. Are you sure you're not doing something elsewhere in your code, that causes this error?

One thing of note however, is that you will only get a single entry output in your resulting `test.json` because you redefine `data1` in every iteration of the loop.